# How can I tell ggplot to avoid plotting the missing dates

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi I have data like this:

```
> x
       value       Date
14 -2.224791 2000-01-31
15 -2.203189 2000-04-30
16 -2.216392 2000-07-31
17 -2.259517 2000-10-31
18 -2.252137 2001-01-31
19 -2.200599 2015-01-31
20 -2.229062 2015-04-30
21 -2.258825 2015-07-31
22 -2.288452 2015-10-31
> ggplot(x,aes(x=Date,y=value))+geom_line()
```

While trying to plot, ggplot is extrapolating for the missing dates i.e between 2001 and 2015. How can I tell ggplot to not plot the values which are not available?
[image]

Comment: `geom_line` connects the points in the data.  You will need to use a different `geom` to show what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

value = c(-2.224791, -2.203189, -2.216392, -2.259517, -2.252137, -2.200599, -2.229062, -2.258825, -2.288452)
date = as.Date(c("2000-01-31","2000-04-30","2000-07-31","2000-10-31","2001-01-31","2015-01-31","2015-04-30","2015-07-31","2015-10-31"))
data = data.frame(value,date)

data_2001 = data %>%
  filter(date <= "2001-12-31")

data_2015 = data %>%
  filter(date >= "2015-01-01")

plot = ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = data_2001
            , aes(x=date,y=value)) +
  geom_line(data = data_2015
            , aes(x=date,y=value))

print(plot)
```

[image]

Comment: in actual data there are two many lines. Changing it to point is very cluttered. It is very straightforward in excel but I am new to R and probably there is something much simple here which I am missing.

Comment: The problem is that you're not explaining what you want very well. ggplot2 isn't extrapolating anything. It is merely connecting the data points in your data set when you use geom_line. With geom_point, it doesn't connect the points. You're saying that neither of these is what you want to play, so what do you want to plot? Are you trying to say you want to plot a fitted curve, like a moving average or a linear regression line? Help us help you. Maybe you could describe how you would use Excel to get your desired result, and then we can use that to figure out what you're trying to do in ggplot.

Comment: sorry if I was not clear. I am trying to tell ggplot to not connect the data points where there is a break. so basically between 2001 and 2015 it should not plot at all, leave it blank, not connect dots. One way I can think is to introduce another column in my data called pre-2001 and post-2015, but that would force ggplot to treat them as separate lines which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Okay, I think I'm with you now. See the code in my edited answer.